# No. of cycles in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

**If $G$ be any graph , then what is the upper bound of the number of cycles in $G$ if I add one edge to $G$?**

it is easy to visualize that adding one edge to $G$ it may not form any cycle (for this if we take one isolated vertex then adding an edge to it does not form any cycle). But is there be any upper bound of it after adding exactly one edge?

I think after adding one edge the no of cycles in $G$ is increased by atmost 1.
So, is there be anything?

Comment: Consider a square, then add a diagonal. You have now increased the number of cycles by $2$.

Comment: Consider a graph with vertices $A,B,C,\dots,V$ and $X$ and $Y$, with edges joining each of $A,B,C,\dots,V$ to both $X$ and $Y$. Now, add an edge joining $X$ and $Y$ – how many cycles does that edge create?

Comment: Are you really interested in the number of cycles in the graph (which is what you said), or are you interested in the number of cycles ***that contain the edge you just added?***

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments and answer, Arindam?

Comment: Are you still here, Arindam?

Comment: Yes .I understood. According to my question there are no upper bound for the no of cycles.But if i add one edge to its spanning tree then there the no of cycle is increasing by exactly one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper bound on the number of cycles created by the new edge.
If for example a graph G has two cycles $xe_1e_2...y...e_k$ and $xe'_1e'_2...y...e'_l$, and $xy \notin E(G)$, then adding the edge $xy$ creates four new cycles $$xe_1e_2...y$$ $$xe_ke_{k-1}...y$$ $$xe'_1e'_2...y$$ $$xe'_le'_{l-1}...y$$
With this example it is easy to see that if we considered 3 cycles, adding the edge would add 6 new cycles, etc.
 If the graph had $n$ of these cycles and we added the edge we would create $2n$ new cycles.

Comment: For another example, taking the complete graph $K_n$ without an edge and adding in that edge creates $n-2 + (n-2)(n-3) + (n-2)(n-3)(n-4) + \dots + (n-2)!$ new cycles.